# Styling for Web Chat

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, web-chat

The default styling for the Web Chat used to be identical to the Bot Emulator. Now, however, there seems to be significantly different default behavior for webchat. I have attached two images below illustrating the differences. My question is: does there exist a ready-made template that will make my Web Chat look and behave the same as the Bot Emulator? I'm aware of the ability to change the styling, but I'd like to make it identical to the Bot Emulator. Notice the difference in color and just general design. Thank you for your time.

Current Webchat

[image: Current Webchat]

Bot Emulator

[image: Bot Emulator]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3406

Comment: I do notice a difference in color, but I don't know what you mean by general design. The Web Chat window in your screenshot happens to be narrow but that's not because of styling. Are you talking about font weight or what?

Comment: For example, the Bot Emulator window is interact-able. When a list of choices is displayed, you can click on it in the emulator and it'll change colors to be a golden one. The same doesn't happen in Web Chat. You can see it in the link below.

https://imgur.com/a/6EqjHlJ

Comment: That's not styling, that's special Emulator functionality. In Emulator you need to be able to select messages so you can view their JSON in the properties panel, but Web Chat has no properties panel. Is your question about making styles match or about introducing a message-highlighting feature to Web Chat?

Comment: My goal is to give the user the exact same interaction with the chat in the web chat embedded on my site as they would get if they connected to the bot emulator. Is that possible? Message highlighting, creating a box around the message when it's clicked, etc

Comment: Oh, and transitions! Forgot about those

Comment: So it's not a styling question after all. Well do you also want to be able to load .bot files? To have a properties panel and a transcript log on the right? To have an endpoints list and a services inspector on the left?

Comment: That's not necessary. All I'm looking for is some unity between the design language of the Bot Emulator and the Web Chat app. As long as it gives the user a place to type, it doesn't need any other abilities (eg looking at json, restarting conversation from here, loading bot, etc). The old version of the Bot Emulator used to look identical to the old version of Web Chat.

Comment: Right now, it seems like your question is too open-ended for Stack Overflow. It's not good enough to say "Notice the difference in color and just general design" because we're not certain to notice the same differences that you're noticing. There's no magic way to just make Web Chat match Emulator automatically, but Web Chat can be customized to look however you want and you can investigate the Emulator source code to see what customizations were made there. Please edit the question to include the specific customizations you want to know how to make, because otherwise there's no way to answer.

Comment: I don't know when the Emulator looked identical to Web Chat, but feel free to link to specific versions of each if you want to use that as a reference. If you just want to use a version of Web Chat that looks identical to any version of Emulator then you can always just use an older version. But if your goal is to get Web Chat to look like the latest version of Emulator specifically then that may be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

BotFramework Emulator is a downstream consumer of Web Chat. Previously, Emulator was not altering any default styling options, but changes were made around version 4.1 or 4.2, I believe. That is why Emulator and Web Chat previously looked identical. If you want your version of Web Chat to match the current look and feel of Emulator, you will need to copy the style options that the Emulator has implemented. [Emulator's Web Chat Theme](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/8201114d055774bbb7acfc2f2915abb3b78b5732/packages/app/client/src/ui/editor/emulator/parts/chat/webChatTheme.ts)